# How can I make Django user logout without a new url page?

Tags: python, django

For logout I am using ready django.contrib.auth.LogoutView and everyone in their tutorials are creating a new url for example '/logout' and my question is how can I use that view without a new url page and html template? Plese use some code for views.py in your answers ;)

Comment: i mean without /logout page

Comment: Please describe what exact behavior you want when you send a request to sign out a user

Comment: I mean how can I make logout without making new logout page /logout ?

Comment: Okay, what page do you want it to be then?

Comment: I mean without sending user to /logout page, for example in Instagram its not sending you to any /logout page its just log out

Comment: You mean you want to send AJAX request and stay on the same page?

Comment: Instagram.com's logout will redirect you to the home page. I posted an answer for a redirect solution.

Comment: can you please say what I have to do in my views.py file with already 2 forms in? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to route the /logout url to a template. You can redirect it to whatever page you want by using the `next_page` attribute ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView)).

You can also look into setting a `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#logout-redirect-url.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any redirects at all and want to stay on the same page, like when you send an AJAX request then you can write your own view like this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.http import HttpResponse

def logout_view(request):
  logout(request)
  return HttpResponse('OK')
```